# How to upload and save streams from a client to Node Server in an mp4

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, video-streaming

I am trying to find a way to save video from a client camera (`navigator.getUserMedia`) **Stream** as **.mp4** onto a **Node.Js server**, but I can't seem to find a way to put it all together.

How can I upload the video stream chunks from the camera to the server and save it in an **.mp4** file.

Thank you all in advance.

**LOCAL ON THE BROWSER :**

```
let myStreamHandler = function (myStream) {
    // Send myStream to server
};

let myErrorHandler = function (error) {
    alert(error);
};

if (typeof navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === "undefined") {
    navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, myStreamHandler, myErrorHandler);
} else {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then(myStreamHandler).catch(myErrorHandler);
}
```

**ON REMOTE NODE SERVER :**

```
var http = require('http');
var router = require('routes')();
var Busboy = require('busboy');
var port = 5000;

// Define our route for uploading files
router.addRoute('/video_stream', function (req, res, params) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {

    // Create an Busyboy instance passing the HTTP Request headers.
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

    // Listen for event when Busboy finds a file to stream.
    busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {

      // We are streaming! Handle chunks
      file.on('data', function (data) {
        // Here we can act on the data chunks streamed and save them as mp4.
    });

      // Completed streaming the file.
      file.on('end', function () {
        console.log('Finished with ' + fieldname);
    });
  });

    // Listen for event when Busboy finds a non-file field.
    busboy.on('field', function (fieldname, val) {
      // Do something with non-file field.
  });

    // Listen for event when Busboy is finished parsing the form.
    busboy.on('finish', function () {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.end();
  });

    // Pipe the HTTP Request into Busboy.
    req.pipe(busboy);
}
});

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  // Check if the HTTP Request URL matches on of our routes.
  var match = router.match(req.url);

  // We have a match!
  if (match) match.fn(req, res, match.params);
});

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I build a node app that takes video camera, and sends it to a Node server. The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/dougsillars/browserLiveStream)

On the Node server, I use FFMPEG to re-encode the video as FLV for a livestream. I then use RTMP to send it to https://api.video to livestream the video via HLS.
(the app is live at [livestream.a.video](https://livestream.a.video) if you are curious).

What you could do is modify the FFMPEG code to not output the RTMP stream, but instead an mp4.

Note that the getUserMedia is using Webm, so the command would look something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -c copy output.mp4
```